# Redirect two separate stdin as input to a program

Tags: c++, pipe, user-input, stdin

The following example outputs the input that comes from `stdin`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string s1, s2;
    while (getline(std::cin, s1))
    {
        std::cout << s1 << " 1\n";
    }

    while (getline(std::cin, s2))
    {
        std::cout << s2 << "2\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I run the program like this: `cat main.cpp | ./main` which outputs

```
#include <iostream> 1
 1
int main(int argc, char **argv) 1
{ 1
 1
    std::string s1, s2; 1
    while (getline(std::cin, s1)) 1
    { 1
        std::cout << s1 << " 1\n"; 1
    } 1
         1
    while (getline(std::cin, s2)) 1
    { 1
        std::cout << s2 << "2\n"; 1
    } 1
} 1
```

Is there a way to pipe two separate inputs to a program through `stdin`? I.e., so if I write something like `cat main.cpp cat main.cpp | ./main`, then the first input gets assigned to `s1` and the second to `s2`?

Comment: Not it's not possible. Not directly any way. It might be possible to splice together input the way you want into a file, and then pipe that single file as input to the program.

Comment: Why not to put these 2 files as parameters to your program instead? and read from 2 ifstream streams instead of cin? ./main main.cpp main.cpp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible, but you can simply use two files containing your input, pass them as a command line argument and read from them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3) 
      return -1;

    std::ifstream ifs1(argv[1]);
    std::ifstream ifs2(argv[2]);

    if (!ifs1.is_open() || !ifs2.is_open())
      return -2;

    std::string s1, s2;
    while (getline(ifs1, s1))
    {
      std::cout << s1 << " 1\n";
    }

    while (getline(ifs2, s2))
    {
      std::cout << s2 << "2\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
./main main.cpp main.cpp
```

You can even make this more flexible, allowing you to read as many files as you wish:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc == 1) 
      return -1; // no input file given

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) { 
      std::ifstream ifs(argv[i]);

      if (!ifs.is_open()) {
        std::cout << argv[i] << ":file not found\n";
        continue;
      }

      std::string line;
      while (getline(ifs, line))
      {
        std::cout << line << " " << i << "\n";
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`cat` doesn't put any kind of separator between the files, so there's no way for the program on the other side of the pipe to know where one file ends and the next one begins. You could do it yourself, with something like:

```
{ cat main.cpp; echo "**END**"; cat main.cpp; } | ./main
```

and change the program to look for the `END` line:

```
while (getline(std::cin, s1) && s1 != "**END**")
{
    std::cout << s1 << " 1\n";
}
```

Comment: Is the second `cat main.cpp` assigned to `s2` this way?

Comment: Yes. The second loop starts running after it reads `**END**`, so it will get whatever is in the second `cat main.cpp`